# Search Active Directory by Canonical Name

Tags: active-directory, powershell

The Manager field for contacts stored in Active Directory holds the CanonicalName of the manager's AD object, not the username or DistinguishedName. I need to be able to search AD for the manager of a mail contact using PowerShell, but Get-ADUser doesn't allow filtering by CanonicalName because it's a constructed attribute, not an actual attribute of the object.

**How can I search AD by Canonical Name using Powershell?**

This command works, but takes too long for scripting purposes because the filter is on the wrong side of the pipe:

Get-ADUser -Filter * -ResultSetSize 10000 -Properties CanonicalName | ?{$_.CanonicalName -eq $MailContact.Manager}

Answer (score 0):

Many times, I only figure out a problem right after I give up and post a question on a forum.

The answer is to get the mail contact using Get-ADObject instead of Get-Contact.

Get-ADUser (Get-ADObject -Filter {Mail -eq $ContactAddress} -Properties Manager).Manager

For whatever reason, Get-ADObject returns the manager attribute as a DistinguishedName, while Get-Contact returns it as a CanonicalName.